# How to create Pie Chart in GWT using gwt-visualization api?

Tags: gwt, google-visualization, pie-chart

I'm trying to build a pie-chart. But i get two different kinds of charts with different jars, gwt-charts & gwt-visualization.

.      [charts image http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/wiki/SimpleVizQuery-1.png](http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/wiki/SimpleVizQuery-1.png)

This is generated using gwt-visualization.jar. But it only displays the detail when I click on it and not when i hover on it. And it has a few more flaws.
.      [image: visualization image]
This is generated using gwt-charts.jar and this is what i want.

Problem is that I need to use gwt-visualization.jar, but I want the look and feel of gwt-charts.jar..

Is there any way for that?????

This is the code example:

```java
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.JsArray;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Panel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.AbstractDataTable;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.VisualizationUtils;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.DataTable;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.Selection;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.AbstractDataTable.ColumnType;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.events.SelectHandler;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.PieChart;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.PieChart.Options;

public class SimpleViz implements EntryPoint {

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        // Create a callback to be called when the visualization API
        // has been loaded.
        Runnable onLoadCallback = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Panel panel = RootPanel.get();

                // Create a pie chart visualization.
                PieChart pie = new PieChart(createTable(), createOptions());


                panel.add(pie);
            }
    };

        // Load the visualization api, passing the onLoadCallback to be called
        // when loading is done.
        VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, PieChart.PACKAGE);
    }

    private Options createOptions() {
        Options options = Options.create();
        options.setWidth(400);
        options.setHeight(240);
        options.set3D(true);
        options.setTitle("My Daily Activities");
        return options;
    }

    private AbstractDataTable createTable() {
        DataTable data = DataTable.create();
        data.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Task");
        data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Hours per Day");
        data.addRows(2);
        data.setValue(0, 0, "Work");
        data.setValue(0, 1, 14);
        data.setValue(1, 0, "Sleep");
        data.setValue(1, 1, 10);
        return data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `gwt-charts` and `gwt-visualization` are simply GWT wrappers for the [google chart javascript library](https://developers.google.com/chart/).

- `gwt-visualization` is the official library but it hasn't been updated for a long time.
- `gwt-charts`is a third party library and is more feature complete wrapper and has been updated to support the recent additions to the google chart javascript library.
  But you can easily achieve the same thing with `gwt-visualization` using [JSNI](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html).

In the end it doesn't really matter which library you use. You should be able to achieve the same looks and behavior with both libraries.

One important thing is to load the `CoreChart.PACKAGE`instead of the `PieChart.PACKAGE` and use the `com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.corechart.PieChart` instead of the `com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.PieChart`:

`VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, CoreChart.PACKAGE);`

Comment: thanks for the answer..but there is no such class as com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.corechart.PieChart in gwt-visualization.

Comment: Then you are not using thr latets version of the gwt-visualization library

Comment: Just to add more info, the last jar is not in the maven repository, you should download it.