# GWT Combo Chart Draw

Tags: javascript, gwt

I'm using [Gwt Combo Chart](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart), How can I describe java script code in java. I got my result in JS, but I need the result in Java, here my JS code:

```js
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

function drawVisualization() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['Month','Income', 'Expense','Average'],
     ['Dec',   100,      200,      150],
     ['Jan',   400,      100,      250],
     ['Feb',   150,      350,      250]
    ]);

    var options = {
      seriesType: 'bars',
      series: {2: {type: 'line'}}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is non **GWT** chart. As I can see - you need some kind of wrapper for that. There is a [library](https://github.com/googlearchive/gwt-google-apis) for that. It's not maintained now, but still working well enough.  Also you can check this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283325/how-to-create-pie-chart-in-gwt-using-gwt-visualization-api).